# Cannot set value in reg file

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm trying to set a multi_sz value, but my code isn't working, and I get no error message or similar.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Start Page"="http://www.yahoo.com"
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /t REG_MULTI_SZ /v "Secondary Start Pages" /d "http://www.bbc.co.uk\0http://www.superuser.com\0" /f
```

The start page works fine, the issue is when trying to add the Secondary Start Pages. The value is not updating (I guess indicating that there is something wrong). I have no idea what is wrong

Comment: When i tried your command in the command prompt, it worked without issue.  I tested it with ie as well and it opened the extra urls correctly.  Are you running it as a .reg or as a .bat?

Comment: As a .reg ... I get a confirmation it succeeded but it doesn't... How odd

Comment: yeah, that `reg add` command in a program that' NOT called by the registry editor, BUT can be called by the command prompt.  This is why you need to use either .reg OR .bat for both entries

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're trying to run the commands as a .reg file, you can use this one:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"Start Page"="http://www.yahoo.com"
"Secondary Start Pages"=hex(7):68,00,74,00,74,00,70,00,3a,00,2f,00,2f,00,77,00,\
  77,00,77,00,2e,00,62,00,62,00,63,00,2e,00,63,00,6f,00,2e,00,75,00,6b,00,00,\
  00,68,00,74,00,74,00,70,00,3a,00,2f,00,2f,00,77,00,77,00,77,00,2e,00,73,00,\
  75,00,70,00,65,00,72,00,75,00,73,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,63,00,6f,00,6d,00,00,\
  00,00,00
```

Here's the same thing as a batch file (name "webpage_defaults.bat" and run it):

```
@echo off
red add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Start Page" /t REG_SZ /d "http://www.yahoo.com" /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main" /v "Secondary Start Pages" /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "http://www.bbc.co.uk\0http://www.superuser.com\0" /f
```